# How to investigate Windows 10 on Mac Mini freezing very frequently

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, mac-mini

For about two months I could work without any troubles.

I don't know whast wa the reason, but about 2-3 days ago my Windows 10 (which I use on Mac Mini) started to freeze, first not so often, now it happens about every 5 minutes and it stays freezed for about 10 to 30 seconds and then back to normal work. I tried to close most of the applications which I was using previously to free RAM, but that didn't change anything.

I looked at Windows Log, but I don't see even errors there in the near past.

This happens during the casual, programming work.
I also noticed that computer is quite hot, I have no idea if it can be relevant.

Where and how should I search for the problem cause?

Comment: How old is it? Failing HDD/SSD could easily cause that. If you know the HDD manufacturer/brand, run the manufacturer HDD testing tool and hopefully that can help to determine if the HDD may be faulty.

Comment: It has about three years. Actually, it seems it helped when I take off notebook from it xD

Comment: Wait wha? :P You had your notebook sitting on top of the Mac mini? ... that is random... tho heat / pressure / vibration on HDD could be a factor... (random but not impossible)

Comment: Seems really weird for me, but I can't think about any other reason that it it better now. Wait a minut, I'll put this notebook on Mac again :D